Angular router reuse strategy - use same component on two routes
I need to use same component on two different routes, and I am reusing both routes. I am following this example:
example
The component has a text field. I am navigating to first route and enter some text into that field. Then I switch to another route, but what I see is the same text I just entered. I thought the router runs two instances of the same class; thus, I should be able to enter different texts into the routes. Any idea?
Thanks

Your expectation is wrong. If the route is running under the same URL, the router will re-use the same component. This way the component doesn't need to be completely destroyed and initialized again when for example the path parameter change. I couldn't find any info on this in the docs, so I'm just adding this as a comment.

what @JSONDerulo mentions is documented here: https://angular.dev/api/router/BaseRouteReuseStrategy - "This base route reuse strategy only reuses routes when the matched router configs are identical. This prevents components from being destroyed and recreated when just the route parameters, query parameters or fragment change (that is, the existing component is reused).
This strategy does not store any routes for later reuse.
Angular uses this strategy by default."

The instances are unique per the routing path, plus there was a typo in the routerLink both point to compA maybe that caused the issue, below I changed both routes to same component and it maintains the state per route (url path).
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'compA',
    component: ComponentA,
  },
  {
    path: 'compB',
    component: ComponentA,
  },
];

Stackblitz Demo

In my real code that actually uses same concept as your example, my routes are unique, but both instances show same data.

@Mark do replicate it, will check it
